# What make guns dangerous

Tags: traducción, gramática

***Lo que hacen las armas muy peligrosas es cuando se los niños utilizan por placer.***

What make guns very dangerous is when kids use them for fun.

Comment: I would use *para divertirse*.

Comment: I closed this because it's not clear what's your question. Are you asking to check if the translation is correct? In that case, the question would be off-topic.

Comment: I thought he was asking about the "sujeto" and "objeto directo".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translation into spanish:

> Lo que hace a las armas muy peligrosas es que los niños las utilicen
>   para divertirse.

The original sentence:

> Lo que hacen las armas muy peligrosas es cuando se los niños utilizan
>   por placer.

Has several mistakes:

- "Hacen" should be "hace" because "hace" is refering to "lo que", not
  "a las armas".
- "las armas" is an indirect object, so we use "a" : "a las armas"
- "cuando se los niños" does not make any sense in spanish.
- "utilizan" is the verb and needs a direct object: "las armas", but to
  avoid repeating "las armas", we use "las" like this: "las utilizan".
- "por placer" is the translation of "for pleasure". "for fun" is
  commonly translated as "por diversion" / "para divertise".